# How to get app version in Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Does anyone know how to get the application version in a Windows Universal app?

There used to be a way reading the xap xaml information in Windows Phone Silverlight apps, but as this changed I can't seem to find a new way of doing this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can read *version* from [Package.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.id.aspx). There you will find:  *Major*, *Minor*, *Build* and *Revision* numbers of your app:

```
string appVersion = string.Format("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",                          
                    Package.Current.Id.Version.Major, 
                    Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor, 
                    Package.Current.Id.Version.Build,
                    Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision);
```