# Change windows phone 8.1 app version while publishing

Tags: version, windows-phone-8.1, publish

I had created an app using AppStudion and later modified it. After completion I had published it on windows phone store, but it display the app version as `2014.1012.1035.4168`. I want to change it to something like `1.1.0.3`, but it won't let me do it.

The input fields are disabled for changing app version are disabled. [image: disabled input fields are disabled]

I have changed the version to `1.1.0.3` in package.appmanifest  also[image: disabled input field]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The strange version stands for appx bundle and you cannot edit it - it's created by the Store.

The app after submission should show up with correct version depending on the device.

Here is also reference to [Rob Caplan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911198/2681948).

For sure the correct version will be after you install the app - [get your App ID from Package.ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145116/2681948) it will be `1.1.0.3`.

Comment: This is wrong. On the store page, the date-based version number will be shown. Only after installing, the "install history" will show the correct version number, which is unsatisfying.

Comment: @MarkusBruckner You are right, I've edited the answer. I'm not sure if the store shows the app with correct version per device for now.