# Get the AppId in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Applications

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, app-id

While attempting to read the `Name` attribute's value from the Package.appxmanifest Identity element using the following line:

```
string PackageName => CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
```

I am getting this exception:

```
The thread 0x22cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x803F6107
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.get_AppId()
   at MyApp.UWP.get_PackageName()
```

Isn't this the normal way to access the Identity element's Name attribute value in the manifest on UWP?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you testing on? I believe Windows Phone 8.1 didn't support this.

Comment: Testing on Windows 10. Windows phone 81 did work with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get app version in Windows Universal App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144054/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-universal-app)

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
string PackageName => Package.Current.Id.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

CurrentApp.AppId is available only after your app is deployed from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using powershell command :

get-StartApps | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'appname'}